# roslaunch changes my PYTHONPATH

Tags: ros, roslaunch, environment, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am running a python script from a callback.  When I run my test code from my shell, I have my environment variables (from my bashrc), more specifically my PYTHONPATH.  However, when I do a roslaunch, PYTHONPATH is only pointing to the ros python modules.  Could anyone offer any suggestions?  Do I need to use the  tags in the launch file?  Is roslaunch overwriting environment variables or is it running in a different shell?  Thank you

Constantin

Edit: I am getting this runtime error as well.  If you notice, there is a missing symbol _Py_ZeroStruct.  I have seen similar error messages and they've always been related to me not linking a library correctly.  In this case it seems the python library may not be linking correctly.  In my example program, I simply use:

```
 -lpython2.6
```

In the CMakeList.txt, I use:

```
 target_link_libraries(ExtractionController python2.6)
```

I have a feeling, ROS is forcing a bad link somewhere though.  Has anyone experienced this?  Thank you.  Here is a print out of the runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in 
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in 
    from lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in 
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in 
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in 
    import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/constantin/workspace/OpenRAVE/src/grasp_behavior_2.py", line 3, in 
    from openravepy import *
  File "/home/constantin/workspace/rospackages/openrave/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openravepy/__init__.py", line 35, in 
    openravepy_currentversion = loadlatest()
  File "/home/constantin/workspace/rospackages/openrave/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openravepy/__init__.py", line 16, in loadlatest
    return _loadversion('_openravepy_')
  File "/home/constantin/workspace/rospackages/openrave/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openravepy/__init__.py", line 19, in _loadversion
    mainpackage = __import__("openravepy", globals(), locals(), [targetname])
  File "/home/constantin/workspace/rospackages/openrave/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openravepy/_openravepy_/__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from openravepy_int import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12119/roslaunch-changes-my-pythonpath/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to find a solution for my first problem.  Using the following code inside a launch file allows me to pass in my PYTHONPATH.  I am assuming this will work for all other environment variables that are being lost as well:

```
<env name="PYTHONPATH" value="$(env PYTHONPATH)" />
```

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) with karma: 296 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1